# Scroll view mistakes

Tags: c#, xaml, scrollview, win-universal-app

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2013.
My project is for Windows universal app.
I have one problem, my scroll view doesn't work.
This is my code:

```
<ScrollViewer
    Height="8000"
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
    VerticalScrollMode="Enabled" 
    AllowDrop="False"
    BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="True" 
    HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" 
    IsHoldingEnabled="True" >
        <Grid>

    <TextBlock
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Margin="108,87,0,0" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="Total points:" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                FontSize="30" 
                Width="176"/>

    <TextBlock 
                x:Name="points" 
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="284,87,0,0" 
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                Text="0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                FontSize="30"
                Width="59" 
                RenderTransformOrigin="3.136,-1.343"/>

    <Image
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Height="56" 
                Margin="322,67,0,0"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Width="48"
                Source="Assets/cup.jpg" 
                Stretch="Fill"/>

</Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: If it's the case that for example the Scrollbars work, but like the mouse-wheel doesn't then just slap `Background="Transparent"` on your ScrollViewer so it becomes hittestvisible.

Comment: @ChrisW. wow, after i added this one then half is scrolling :O

Comment: Oh yea, I didn't even look at the height there. Yep your Viewport can't be that big, you're making the the Measure() and Arrange() pass choke. Why you'd need something that huge hard set anyway is beyond me.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ScrollViewer Height is way too big. Shrink it to 50 and see the result. Just for test, i am not sure what the container for this is. I see you are working with strange margins, don't try to drag and drop items but define them by hand and you will get better arranging.

Answer (score 1):

could you change HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" and horizontalscrollmode="Enabled". Change your height also.